# concat string and variable in twig

Tags: twig

I have this in my template

```
    {{ ad.title_de }}
```

Now I'm incorporating multiple languages, so 'title_de' has to change
I also have a variable 'tld' which  is one of  de, en , fr

So I'd like to have something like

```
    {% if tld == 'fr' %} 
    {{ ad.title_fr }}
```

etc
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `attribute` function.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

`attribute(ad, 'content_'~tld)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
{{ ad["title_" ~ tld] }}
```